# How to look through only the next few lines of a txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am scraping a text file in Python using a for loop and if statements to determine if a line has certain elements and returning those elements. It is simple enough if my element is on the same line as the key, but I am not sure how to create "sub-blocks" of the txt file and then iterate only through those.

What I mean is, if I have

```
    WKU  D02807769
SRC  6
APN  427637&
APT  4
ART  292
APD  19820929
TTL  Athletic shoe with pocket
ISD  19851001
NCL  1
ECL  1
EXP  Holtje; Nelson C.
NDR  2
NFG  4
TRM  14
INVT
NAM  Gamm; Robert J.
CTY  St. Louis
STA  MO
ASSG
NAM  Kangaroos U.S.A., Inc.
CTY  St. Louis
STA  MO
COD  02
RLAP
...
...
UREF
PNO  D110163
ISD  19380600
NAM  Andrews
UREF
PNO  D116598
ISD  19390900
NAM  Pick
UREF
PNO  D130845
ISD  19411200
NAM  Pick
UREF
```

it is simple enough to return "D02807769" by looking for WKU, but I am not sure how to proceed if I want to look through only (for example) the elements after ASSG, but before the next tag (in this case "RLAP", but it could be something else, although the number of lines would be the same).

For example, if I wanted to return the value for NAM ("Kangaroos U.S.A., Inc.") under ASSG, but not the other values for NAM in the file, I am not sure how I would do that.

I've tried a while statement:
    while line.startswith("ASSG") or len(line) > 4:

but that seemed to give me an infinite loop. I also tried

```
line.next()
```

but got an error AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

I am not sure how to get at these indirect blocks to search them for what I am looking for. I assume it's a for loop of some kind, but I am not sure how to write that

Comment: are you sure it will always be 4 lines? or do you need to search where the next tag is

Comment: @ofer sadan I'm not sure it will always be 4 lines. I'd like to be able to call it as needed (so, in my example for the 4 lines after ASSG but also for the three lines after INVT as well

Comment: @JohnDoe I guess the question is, how would you identify a block , is 'block' something between two lines where both lines only contain a single contiguous string in it?

Answer (score 0):

Break the search for the value into two steps:

1. Find the category (ASSG)
2. Find the key (NAM)

If you find another category during step 2, abort the search.

```
def find_value(infile, category, key):
    # first, search for the category header - a line with a single word
    for line in infile:
        line= line.strip()
        if line == category:
            # we found the category header, now search for a line that
            # starts with the key
            key = key + ' '
            for line in infile:
                if line.startswith(key):
                    return line[len(key):].lstrip()

                # if this is another category header, stop searching
                line = line.strip()
                if not ' ' in line:
                    break
```

Test run:

```
>>> print(find_value(infile, 'ASSG', 'NAM'))
Kangaroos U.S.A., Inc.
```

---

Alternatively, you can use regex:

```
import re

def find_value(infile, category, key):
    text = infile.read()
    template = r'(?sm)^{category}$\s+^(?:\S+ +\S[^\n]*$\s+^)*{key}\s+([^\r\n]+)'
    pattern = template.format(category=re.escape(category),
                              key=re.escape(key))
    match = re.search(pattern, text)
    if match is None:
        return None
    return match.group(1)
```

This regex does pretty much the same thing - it searches for a line that equals "ASSG", then searches for a line that starts with "NAM", and aborts the search if it finds a line that only contains a single word.